# Running java from Terminal: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I have always been coding from `NetBeans` interface, but I would like to learn to do it from `ubuntu` terminal, which I can hardly use.

The file I want to run is `TabRemover.java`. I reach its directory from the terminal and write:

```
simone@Pargolo:~/NetBeansProjects/TabRemover/src/tabremover$ java TabRemover
```

But I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TabRemover (wrong name: tabremover/TabRemover)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
```

What should I do to run a Java program from Ubuntu terminal? I saw there are different threads on the topic in the web, but they do not look like helping...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You need set classpath    -cp option in comandline
and off course you need compile it before with javac

```
$cd ~/NetBeansProjects/TabRemover/src
$java -classpath . org.tabremover.TabRemover
```

-classpath  and -cp — give save effect.

Please check that TabRemover.java located in ~/NetBeansProjects/TabRemover/src/org/tabremover/TabRemover.java

org/tabremover should be equivalent package name  org.tabremover

Comment: Thank you iMysak for your answer. What is a classpath? How can I set it?

Comment: I have checked the page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29. I supposed that in order to create a classpath I had to write:
java -classpath /home/NetBeansProjects/TabRemover/src/tabremover org.tabremover.TabRemover
Why do I get:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.tabremover.TabRemover

Comment: I update answer, you should launch this command from base dir which contain package.